# Use null values on react-native-chart-kit

Tags: react-native, expo

I am using expo react-native-chart-kit https://github.com/indiespirit/react-native-chart-kit

I want to have a line for the days of the week, but sometimes some days may not have values, so I need to ignore some days and continue the graph to the next day that has record, how can I do it?